# Term to describe change from /yeho/ to /yo/ in biblical Hebrew names

Tags: terminology, hebrew

The first two syllables on many biblical Hebrew names with the initial theophoric element יְהוֹ *yeho* were abbreviated to יוֹ *yo*.

[image]

For example,  *Yehochanan* became *Yochanan*. I was curious what the linguistic term was for such a syllabific abbreviation if it was primarily due to the /eh/ simply dropping out of /yeho/ because of the preference for saying /yo/ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be [Elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), the loss of sounds, usually *unstressed* ones.

Further reading:

- [Terms for changes in pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_change#Terms_for_changes_in_pronunciation);
- [Grimm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law), a set of statements that discuss the *systematic* nature of sound changes;

As you mentioned, this very example of elision had mostly religious (not linguistic) reason, so the change may be irregular.

Comment: I am not so sure the reason was mostly religious. I simply noticed it in a religious context, but it certainly could have primarily been due to a linguistic reason. After all, the Jewish people were influenced by various cultures with their own languages.